# Angular 7, NGXS & Firestore: Redundancy Concerns

Tags: angular, architecture, google-cloud-firestore, angular7, ngxs

Currently, I fetch data from Firestore and then patch this into the state. I also use the NGXS Storage Plugin.

It all works, but it seems redundant.

When I fetch state, I use a combination of regular and joined @Selectors. This means that I'm not taking advantage of the Firestore Query options and my code ends up becoming bloated in terms of size and complexity.

When using Firestore with enablePersistence, is NGXS really needed?

What could be done to streamline the architecture?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why the downvote? @Wayne Riesterer maybe softwareengineering.stackexchange.com is more appropriate.

Comment: No problem. I never considered the other options but will try there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

NGXS / ngrx is there to help you manage state in your application. This can include important stuff, like actual data, or unimportant items, like the state of a checkbox, a selection in a dropdown.

In large applications, where you want to know the exact state of the UI, a state management library, can be useful as it offers an immutable UI state over an observable that you can react to.

In your case, Firestore, can store your data, and provide the event source (observable) when your data changes. But this is your actual, important, data. You will not store at firestore the filter that a user put in a data grid. You will not store there, the current route of the router, or the color of the theme that he wanted for the app.

NGXS can store this part of your state, that firestore should not store. If you don't use NGXS, then you're not immutably managing that state, which may or may not be important (if you don't mind too much about inconsistencies in the UI/UX it's not a big deal)

---

Let's assume that you don't care about the dumb UI state (buttons colors etc) that much.

Putting your firestore state in a redux store, offers the following advantages:

1. You abstract over firestore. If tomorrow you decide that
   firestore is too expensive, or waterstore does things better, you
   can switch to it, and your app will not know the difference, because
   your app depends on NGXS.
2. Other developers that know how to work with Redux, can more
   easily reason about your application.
3. You have full control over your state, not Firestore. Firestore,
   as great as it is, is kind of a black box. With NGXS you can fully
   manage when something changes in your app, and have an appropriate
   action that caused it. You can, for example, when an error occurs,
   send the previous 10 states + the last action to a logging server,
   and replay that on your machine. With Firestore, you don't know how
   or why a change occurred.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I never considered the benefits of abstraction but think this is a great reason in itself. I still haven't seen an implementation I find clean though. Using a GetAllWhatevers action that fetches data and patches the state makes sense for one-shot http calls, but seems odd with Firestore which returns observables. Subscription problems cause errors too. I am considering using StartStream actions and onStateChanges, but not sure yet if this is the best option either.

Comment: @WayneRiesterer Don't think about it too much. Just implement it one way, and see if it works for you. It's actually great to learn from an approach with drawbacks. Perfect is the enemy of good.